# How to write javascript for multiple inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm using multiple inputs in my application and I want to filter the 2nd dropdown based on the selection of 1st dropdown.

```
@foreach (range(1, 5) as $x)
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="course-{{ $x }}">
                             Course #{{$x}}
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="Course{{$x}}" id="Course{{$x}}" required="true">
                                <option selected value='0'>--Select Course--</option>
                                @foreach($Courses as $crs)
                                    <option value="{{$crs->Code}}">{{$crs->Code}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="Subject-{{ $x }}">Subject </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="Subject{{$x}}" id="Subject{{$x}}" required="true">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
@endforeach
```

My problem is how can I write the js on change of the 1st dropdown for these multiple inputs?

```
$("#Course").on("change", function()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a class in the 1st dropdown. after that, you can tract it by Id. For example:

```
 <select name="Course{{$x}}" class="courses" id="Course{{$x}}" required="true">
```

and you can track it by ID

```
$(".courses").on("change", function(){
    courseId = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Now you have the selected course Id, you can change your 2nd dropdown based on the selection of 1st dropdown.

Comment: Thanks. Can u plz help me further to change the 2nd dropdown? My 2nd dropdown look like this. `<select name="Subject{{$x}}" id="Subject{{$x}}" required="true">
                            </select>`

Comment: Do you want to get subjects from server end? If it is true then you have to call ajax, to get subjects of the selected course.

Comment: Is there any other method?

Comment: @Srima, if you have an object of subjects then you can filter it on javascript end and update the options of drop down of subject.
Like : 
Subjects = [
  { courseid: 1, id: 1, name: "Subject 1" },
  { courseid: 1, id: 2, name: "Subject 2" },
  { courseid: 2, id: 3, name: "Subject 3" },
  { courseid: 2, id: 4, name: "Subject 4" },
  { courseid: 3, id: 7, name: "Subject 5" },
];

But getting the result from ajax call is a good approach.